# How to iterate through Dictionary<MyEnum, List<int>> and each time return part of values of each list?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, dictionary

Each key in dictionary has list of **MANY** integers. I need to iterate through each key and each time to take n items from list and do it until I iterate through **all items in all lists**. What is the best way to implement it? Do I need to implement some Enumerator?

The code:

```
enum ItemType { Type1=1, Type2=2, Type3=3 };

var items = new Dictionary<ItemType, List<int>>();
items[ItemType.Type1] = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
items[ItemType.Type2] = new List<int> { 11, 12, 13, 15 };
items[ItemType.Type3] = new List<int> { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 };
```

For example: n=2.

1. 1st iteration returns 1,2,11,12,21,22
2. 2nd iteration returns 3,4,13,15,23,24
3. 3rd iteration returns 5,25,26

**UPDATED**: 
at the end I have to get list of this items in that order : 1,2,11,12,21,22,  3,4,13,15,23,24,   5,25,26

Comment: Are lists always the same length? What behavior do you expect, when `Count` doesn't multiple of `n`?

Comment: No. As shown in example: 1st list has 5 elements, 2nd has 4, 3rd has 6

Comment: @theateist I hope you haven't abandoned this question and will be back to mark an answer or at least indicate which answer(s) were helpful. Out of your 114 questions you will have approx 30 that need an answer marked (if it has been answered satisfactorily), each marked answer will earn you an extra 2 rep points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it might be done:

```
enum ItemType { Type1 = 1, Type2 = 2, Type3 = 3 };

Dictionary<ItemType, List<int>> items = new Dictionary<ItemType, List<int>>();
items[ItemType.Type1] = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
items[ItemType.Type2] = new List<int> { 11, 12, 13, 15 };
items[ItemType.Type3] = new List<int> { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 };

// Define upper boundary of iteration
int max = items.Values.Select(v => v.Count).Max();

int i = 0, n = 2;
while (i + n <= max)
{
    // Skip and Take - to select only next portion of elements, SelectMany - to merge resulting lists of portions
    List<int> res = items.Values.Select(v => v.Skip(i).Take(n)).SelectMany(v => v).ToList();
    i += n;

    // Further processing of res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
var resultList = new List<int>();
items.ToList().ForEach(listInts => resultList.AddRange(listInts.Take(n));
```

This is letting LINQ extensions do the hard work for you. [Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22System.Linq.Enumerable.Take%60%601%22%29;k%28SolutionItemsProject%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.0%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) will take as much as it can without throwing an exception if you request more than what there is. In this case I'm adding the results to another list, but you could just as easily tag another [ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22System.Collections.Generic.List%601.ForEach%22%29;k%28SolutionItemsProject%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.0%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) on the end of the `Take()` in order to iterate the results.

I notice from the example sequences that you are retriving *n* number of items from *x* starting point - if you edit your question to include how the starting point is decided then I will adjust my example.

---

## Edit:

Because you want to take *n* number of items from each list each iteration until there are no more elements returned, this will do it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var items = new Dictionary<ItemType, List<int>>();
        items[ItemType.Type1] = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        items[ItemType.Type2] = new List<int> { 11, 12, 13, 15 };
        items[ItemType.Type3] = new List<int> { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 };

        int numItemsTaken = 0;
        var resultsList = new List<int>();
        int n = 2, startpoint = 0, previousListSize = 0;

        do
        {
            items.ToList().ForEach(x => resultsList.AddRange(x.Value.Skip(startpoint).Take(n)));
            startpoint += n;
            numItemsTaken = resultsList.Count - previousListSize;
            previousListSize = resultsList.Count;
        } 
        while (numItemsTaken > 0);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", resultsList));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    enum ItemType { Type1 = 1, Type2 = 2, Type3 = 3 };
}
```

This is one of the few times you'll use a `do while` loop, and it will work regardless of the size of `n` or the size of your lists or how many lists there are.

Comment: It's not what the question want. The iteration shouldn't start from beginning every time.

Comment: It should eventually return all items of all lists in dictionary, but it should return in following order: n items from **list1**, n items from list2, n items from list3, n items from **list1**, n items from list2....

Comment: You can't do .ForEach() on a Dictionary, I updated your answer

Comment: It does not compile. And it will return only `1,2,11,12,21,22`, what about other items?

Comment: @theateist I have updated my answer with a working compiling example. If this is homework or an assignment you might not want to submit it exactly as you see it, or you should learn the details of what I've used.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define your custom enumerator, just use the `MoveNext` manually:

Step 1, convert you `Dictionary<ItemType, List<int>>` into `Dictionary<ItemType, List<IEnumerator<int>>`:

```
var iterators = items.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => (IEnumerator<int>)p.Value.GetEnumerator());
```

Step 2: handle `MoveNext` manually:

```
public List<int> Get(Dictionary<ItemType, IEnumerator<int>> iterators, int n)
{
    var result = new List<int>();

    foreach (var itor in iterators.Values)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < n && itor.MoveNext(); i++)
        {
            result.Add(itor.Current);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Calling `Get` multiple times will give you the expected result. The enumerator itself will keep the current position.

Answer (score 0):

The "best way" depends on your goal, e.g. readability or performance.

Here's one way:

```
var firstIter = items.Values.SelectMany(list => list.Take(2));
var secondIter = items.Values.SelectMany(list => list.Skip(2).Take(2));
var thirdIter = items.Values.SelectMany(list => list.Skip(4).Take(2));

var finalResult =  firstIter.Concat(secondIter).Concat(thirdIter);
```

**Edit:** Here's a more general version:

```
var finalResult = Flatten(items, 0, 2);

IEnumerable<int> Flatten(
    Dictionary<ItemType, List<int>> items, 
    int skipCount, 
    int takeCount)
{
    var iter = items.Values.SelectMany(list => list.Skip(skipCount).Take(takeCount));

    return
        iter.Count() == 0 ?  // a bit inefficient here
        iter :
        iter.Concat(Flatten(items, skipCount + takeCount, takeCount));
}
```